Cómo calcular la cota de error de Lagrange con codigo en matlab?
Sea $3xe^x - e^{2x}$
a) Aproxima $f(1.03)$ mediante el polinomio de interpolación de Hermite de grado tres usando $x0 = 1$ y $x1 = 1.05$. Compare el error real con el límite de error.
b) Repita (a) con el polinomio de interpolación de Hermite de grado cinco, usando $x0 = 1, x1 = 1,05 y x2 = 1,07.$
He agregado una línea de código para calcular el límite de error, pero no se ejecuta: ¿Pueden ayudarme? Sólo necesito calcular el nivel de error, porque este código ya muestra el error real
`%--------------------------------------------------
function P = HPoly(x,y,yp)
    n = length(x) ;
    for k=1:(2*n)
        Bx(:,k)=x'.^(k-1) ;
    end
    Bp(:,1)=zeros(n,1) ;
    for k=2:(2*n)
        Bp(:,k)=(k-1)*x'.^(k-2) ;
    end
    P = flip([Bx;Bp]\[y,yp]')';
end
%--------------------------------------------------
function y = f(x)
    y = 3*x.*exp(x)-exp(2*x) ;
end
function y = fp(x)
    y = 3*exp(x).*(x + 1) - 2*exp(2*x);
end
%--------------------------------------------------
% GRADO 3
%
x  = [1, 1.05] ;
y  = f(x) ;
yp = fp(x);

xtest = 1.03 ;
%--------------------------------------------------

P = HPoly(x,y,yp) ;
Err3 = polyval(P,xtest) - f(xtest)
function Lagrange_error_bound = max(abs((xtest-x(1))*(xtest-x(2)))*(abs(fp(t))/(2*factorial(3))), abs((xtest-x(1))*(xtest-x(2))*(xtest-x(3)))*(abs(fp(t))/(6*factorial(4))));
  end
xb = [1:.001:1.05];
yb = f(xb) ;
H = polyval(P,xb) ;

subplot(2,2,1);plot(xb,yb,"r",xb,H,"g",x,y,"r*")
subplot(2,2,2);plot(xb,H-yb,xtest,Err3,"r*")

%--------------------------------------------------

% GRADO 5
%
x  = [1, 1.05, 1.07] ;
y  = f(x) ;
yp = fp(x);

xtest = 1.03 ;
%--------------------------------------------------

P = HPoly(x,y,yp) ;
Err5 = polyval(P,xtest) - f(xtest)

xb = [1:.001:1.07];
yb = f(xb) ;
H = polyval(P,xb) ;

subplot(2,2,3);plot(xb,yb,"r",xb,H,"g",x,y,"r*")
subplot(2,2,4);plot(xb,H-yb,xtest,Err5,"r*")
%--------------------------------------------------

He agregado una línea de código para calcular el límite de error, pero no se ejecuta: ¿Pueden ayudarme? Sólo necesito calcular el nivel de error.`

